# Why does kable in R undo an summarytools frequency option to not display cumulative percentage?

Tags: r, r-markdown, tibble, kable, summarytools

I found an odd quirk or maybe an intentional feature and trying to find a more elegant solution.  Any ideas are appreciated.  Reproducible code example below, but I wasn't able to recreate the tables very well here with markdown.

Situation: When I use the `freq()` function from the *summarytools* package, I remove the total cumulate results using the `cumul=FALSE` argument for a cleaner output.  This works as expected.  However, when I pipe the results into a `kable()` table from the *knitr* and *kableExtra* packages, the total cumulative results appear in the kable table.  Not sure why.

According to summarytools creator Dominic Comtois' page [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/summarytools/vignettes/introduction.html):

> *summarytools* objects are not always compatible with packages focused on table formatting, such as *formattable* or *kableExtra*. However, `tb()` can be used as a “bridge”, an intermediary step turning `freq()` and descr() objects into simple tables that any package can work with.

I assume my problem is part of the mentioned compatibility issue.  When I add a `tb()` as bridge between `freq()` and `kable()`, my table contents appear as they should without the total cumulative results.  Yet, the table headings no longer retain their heading names and revert to using the tibble's assigned column headings.  Also, I lose the Total row on the bottom.

So far, I managed to rename the tibble column names to be closer to the original `freq()` output, but haven't yet restored the bottom Totals row.  I assume there is a better code approach than what I've done thus far.  Thanks in advance!

```
# set packages and data
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(summarytools)
library(kableExtra)
set.seed(99)
d <- data.frame(group=sample(LETTERS[1:3], size=100, replace=TRUE))

# initial frequency output
d |> freq(group, cumul=FALSE)

# move freq results in kable add the Total Cumulative back
d |> freq(group, cumul=FALSE) |> 
     kable() |> kable_classic(full_width=FALSE)

# changing to a tibble before kable drops the Totals row and reverts the column headings
d |> freq(group, cumul=FALSE) |> tb() |> 
     kable() |> kable_classic(full_width=FALSE)

# minor fix on the column headings but still not totals row
d |> freq(group, cumul=FALSE) |> tb() |> 
     rename("Group"="group", "Freq"="freq", "% Valid"="pct_valid", "% Valid Cum."="pct_tot")|> 
     kable() |> kable_classic(full_width=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more straightforward solution:

```
set.seed(99)
d <- data.frame(group=sample(c(LETTERS[1:3], NA), size=500, replace=TRUE))

freq(d$group)[,-c(3,5)] |>
  kable(digits = 1) |>
  kable_classic(full_width = FALSE)
```

[image: First result table]

To have the "Group" column title:

```
as.data.frame(freq(d$group)[,-c(3,5)]) |> 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Group") |>
  kable(digits = 1) |>
  kable_classic(full_width = FALSE)
```

[image: Second results table]

The reason `kable()` ends up displaying the cumulative columns is that `freq()` returns a matrix which always contains cumulatives; it is *summarytools*'  `print()` function that determines which columns and heading elements to mask / show, based on the *freq* object's attributes. (Check `attributes(freq(d$group)`, you'll see what I mean).

An extra tip for displaying frequency tables with a "valid" column: use the following knitr/kable options:

```
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
```

This way, we have a blank cell in lieu of "NA":

[image: Third results table]

Comment: Thanks!  That's really interesting how you added the Group column title as omitted the NA within the % Valid column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible but verbose solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(summarytools)
library(kableExtra)

set.seed(99)
d <- data.frame(group=sample(LETTERS[1:3], size=100, replace=TRUE))

d |> 
  freq(group, cumul=FALSE) |> 
  tb() |> 
  (function(df){
    bind_rows(df, data.frame(group = "Total", freq = sum(df$freq), pct_valid = 100, pct_tot = 100))
  })() |>
  rename(Group = group, Freq = freq, `% Valid` = pct_valid , `% Total` = pct_tot ) |> 
  kable() |> 
  kable_classic(full_width=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  That gets me to where I need to be with the output.  Any idea why that occurs in the first place?